# First ResultSet.next() call is taking more then a minute

Tags: jdbc, oracle11g

I am using JDBC api to call a store procedure. Which returns a cursor. Problem I am facing is, first two call of ResultSet.next() take more then a minute to return result. After then it take less then 2 seconds. Is it the case of every one or need to customize the call.

```
OracleCallableStatement cs =  (OracleCallableStatement)DBTransaction.createCallableStatement("begin " + "sql_package.stored_proc(?,?,?,?,?,?)" + "; end;", DBTransaction.DEFAULT);
rs = cs.getCursor(1);
rs.next();// The culprit.
```

JAVA 1.6, Oracle 11i

Comment: Are you sure that it isn't just the time the DB needs to collect the data which it is been asked for and/or the time the JDBC driver needs to haul it over network into Java's memory? More than one minute sounds like an inefficient query and/or a slow network with a high latency and/or just a zillion or rows in the result set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was Query what was taking time.